# Tableau filter where a condition is met several months in a row

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am trying to show when sales in superstore are >10000 in x months in a row.
For example, I'd like to be able to show a flag for when one category has >10000 2+ months running. Ideally, it would just be a 1 for each month it gets to 2 consecutive months. I have tried a running total and using that as a filter but it's not the prettiest solution.
[image]

Comment: use the measure "Sales > 10000" as a color in Marks pane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOOKUP. This will be TRUE if the current month and the previous month are both greater than 10,000.

[image]

Comment: I just wrapped this in an if statement with the above = True else false and it gave me the desired outcome. It still didn't work for a filter as I intended but it will get me out of trouble. Thank you